# Method optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, readability

I have a void function that has a lot of if statements in it and all of them are required I really can't remove anything. But I feel like that it could be done better. Using some `LINQ.Where`, classes or something like this. I want to optimize and express `void Smooth` in the fewest characters possible :

```
    void Smooth(ref int botChips, ref bool botTurn, Label botStatus, int name, int n, int r) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rnd = rand.Next(1, 3);
        if (rounds == 0 || rounds == 1)
        {
            if (call <= 0)
            {
                Check(ref botTurn, botStatus);
            }
            else
            {
                if (call >= RoundN(botChips, n))
                {
                    Call(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (botChips >= call * 2)
                    {
                        Raise *= 2;
                        Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Call(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (rounds == 2 || rounds == 3)
        {
            if (call <= 0)
            {
                if (rnd == 1)
                {
                    Raise = RoundN(botChips, r);
                    Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
                }
                else if (rnd!=1 && rounds==2)
                {
                    Check(ref botTurn, botStatus);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (call >= RoundN(botChips, r))
                {
                    if (botChips > call)
                    {
                        Call(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
                    }
                    if (botChips <= call)
                    {
                        raising = false;
                        botTurn = false;
                        botChips = 0;
                        botStatus.Text = "Call " + call;
                        tbPot.Text = (int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + call).ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Raise <= (RoundN(botChips, r)) / 2)
                    {
                        Raise = RoundN(botChips, r);
                        Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Raise *= 2;
                        Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**`RoundN` method**

```
    private static double RoundN(int sChips, int n) {
        double a = Math.Round((sChips / n) / 100d, 0) * 100;
        return a;
    }
```

**`Fold` method**

```
    private void Fold(ref bool sTurn, ref bool SFTurn, Label sStatus) {
        raising = false;
        sStatus.Text = "Fold";
        sTurn = false;
        SFTurn = true;
    }
```

**`Check` method**

```
    private void Check(ref bool cTurn, Label cStatus) {
        cStatus.Text = "Check";
        cTurn = false;
        raising = false;
    }
```

**`Call` method**

```
    private void Call(ref int sChips, ref bool sTurn, Label sStatus) {
        raising = false;
        sTurn = false;
        sChips -= call;
        sStatus.Text = "Call " + call;
        tbPot.Text = (int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + call).ToString();
    }
```

**`Raised` method**

```
    private void Raised(ref int sChips, ref bool sTurn, Label sStatus) {
        sChips -= Convert.ToInt32(Raise);
        sStatus.Text = "Raise " + Raise;
        tbPot.Text = (int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(Raise)).ToString();
        call = Convert.ToInt32(Raise);
        raising = true;
        sTurn = false;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try profiling? BTW I would define the `Random` only once and split this big method into few smaller ones (`Ctrl+R, M`)

Comment: I know this is not what you asked, but that is a very dangerous use of `new Random`; if you call `Smooth` in a loop it could use the same seed. You should make `rand` an instance variable and initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer's ! No i haven't tried profiling and i will fix the `new Random`

Comment: Define _optimize_. Do you want to profile the input values and restructure the code to be as fast as possible for the most common inputs, regardless of how cryptic? Do you want the code expressed in the fewest characters possible? Fewest memory cache misses? ...

Comment: I want the code expressed in the fewest characters possible. I will add this in my question description thanks for the correction .

Comment: Why do you want to optimize for number of characters in the code? Unless you have performance problems the only "optimization" I would perform would be to refactor it to avoid all those nested if-statements. Something like the "rule pattern" (look it up on Pluralsight) would be good here, but it would add a lot more characters, but would also be a lot more maintainable in the future.

Comment: Also, if the code works, the correct place to ask a question like this would be [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The place to ask "how short can you make this code?" is to ask a code golf question on the puzzle site. But shorter code is seldom more understandable, faster, better code. It's just shorter. If what you want is to make your code more elegant and understandable then that's very different than making it shorter. Start by eliminating all those refs. If you're computing values, pass the values back rather than modifying variables.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In a way yes, but the OP said _I want to optimize and express void Smooth in the fewest characters possible_ if he wants CodeGolf than CodeReview is not for him. Also a CodeReview question must have a description of what the code does

Comment: You're right, if golfing is what he wants but I doubt he wants to go that far. Most likely he has a feeling that reducing the number of characters will give him some other benefit.

Comment: I'm sorry if asked the question in the wrong section but I'm new to stackoverflow as you can see my reputation.. But I guess I will just leave it just as it is since it's working and I don't find any performance problems. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Smooth` method can be *simplified* (or in your term: optimized?) in some ways:

1. To remove the conditional (`if-else`) nested blocks, consider the use of early `return` for conditions which are simpler among the two or has no further continuation. This way, you may remove "difficult-to-read" nested blocks.
2. To avoid "duplicate" blocks, blocks with identical actions should be considered to be grouped together rather than being separated.
3. Think if reversing the condition can help to simplify your code
4. Exploit whatever beneficial behaviors that you know about the language evaluation. For instance, [for C#](https://www.tradingcode.net/csharp/operators/short-circuit-evaluation/), in the argument of the conditional statement like `if (a || b)` case, the **left** expression (that is: `a`) will be evaluated first - this is known as [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).
5. Whenever possible, and without significantly losing the readability, consider of using [Ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to replace `if-else` block.
6. Declare variable that you will be using multiple times without changing the value only *once*
7. Watch out for overlapping (doubled/duplicated) conditions!
8. Use **correct** data type *will* help!

For your case, the simplified code can be something like this

```
uint rounds = 0; //read 8.
void Smooth(ref int botChips, ref bool botTurn, Label botStatus, int name, int n, int r) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rnd = rand.Next(1, 3);
    if (rounds <= 1) { //read 8.
        if (call <= 0) {
            Check(ref botTurn, botStatus); //since your Check doesn't change rounds, this is legal                  
            return; //read 1. early return                  
        } //beyond this call > 0
        if (call >= RoundN(botChips, n) || botChips < call * 2) { //read 2., 3., 4., and 7.
            Call(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
            return; //read 1.
        } //beyond this is the opposite of both conditions
        Raise *= 2;
        Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
    }

    if (rounds == 2 || rounds == 3) {
        if (call <= 0) {
            if (rnd == 1) { //call <= 0, rnd == 1, similar to the block on call < rNBChips, may potentially be further simplified
                Raise = RoundN(botChips, r);
                Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
            } else if (rounds == 2) //read 7. rnd is definitely not 1, no need for further check
                Check(ref botTurn, botStatus);
            return; //read 1. this is valid since you don't want to continue
        }
        double rNBChips = RoundN(botChips, r); //read 6. this way you avoid multiple calls. It both shorter and faster
        if (call < rNBChips) { //read 3.
            Raise = Raise <= rNBChips / 2 ? rNBChips : Raise * 2; //read 5.
            Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
            return; // read 1.
        }
        if (botChips > call) {
            Call(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
            return; //read 1.
        }
        raising = false;
        botTurn = false;
        botChips = 0;
        botStatus.Text = "Call " + call;
        tbPot.Text = (int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + call).ToString();
    }
}
```

Without the comments it even looks a lot more compact, like this

```
uint rounds = 0;
void Smooth(ref int botChips, ref bool botTurn, Label botStatus, int name, int n, int r) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rnd = rand.Next(1, 3);
    if (rounds <= 1) {
        if (call <= 0) {
            Check(ref botTurn, botStatus);              
            return; 
        }
        if (call >= RoundN(botChips, n) || botChips < call * 2) {
            Call(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
            return;
        }
        Raise *= 2;
        Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
    }

    if (rounds == 2 || rounds == 3) {
        if (call <= 0) {
            if (rnd == 1) {
                Raise = RoundN(botChips, r);
                Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
            } else if (rounds == 2)
                Check(ref botTurn, botStatus);
            return;
        }
        double rNBChips = RoundN(botChips, r);
        if (call < rNBChips) {
            Raise = Raise <= rNBChips / 2 ? rNBChips : Raise * 2;
            Raised(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
            return;
        }
        if (botChips > call) {
            Call(ref botChips, ref botTurn, botStatus);
            return;
        }
        raising = false;
        botTurn = false;
        botChips = 0;
        botStatus.Text = "Call " + call;
        tbPot.Text = (int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + call).ToString();
    }
}
```