# Better way to write if-else block

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I have following code (Sample code) which works very well.
I just think if there is any other better way we can write following code snippet more accurately with less code.

```
if(language == "English")
{
    if(Student_id == 0)
    {
        someFunction();
    }
    else
    {
        if(getMarks(Student_id) > 50 || subjectCount > 1 || projectCount > 0)
        {
            someFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, please note if `Student_id` is `0`, `getMarks(Student_id)` throws error

Comment: This is more suited for [codereview.se].

Comment: Is "someFunction();" the same function in both lines?

Comment: @nvoigt yes it is the same function

Comment: My apologies!! I missed one condition in code. Please see my edit

Answer (score 11):

*(For more a complex scenario, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383934/method-optimization/34389030#34389030))*

What I suggest for your case is:

1. To write it with less nested `if-else` block

   - one way to do it is by *inverting the conditions* and
   - gives *early return* whenever possible
2. To combine conditions with the same actions (in your case being the `someFunction`)
3. To exploit the [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which is implemented in [C#](https://www.tradingcode.net/csharp/operators/short-circuit-evaluation/) (also implemented in many other programming languages - as noted by [Martheen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529282/martheen) in his comment).

   ```
   if(language != "English")
       return; //assuming nothing below

   if(Student_id == 0 || getMarks(Student_id) > 50 || subjectCount > 1 || projectCount > 0)
       someFunction(); //if someFunction is identical, this can be done
   ```

   If you have other languages to be checked or if you have something to be done independent from your actions based on `language == "English"`, however, then you should not return in the `if (language != "English")` statement:

   ```
   if(language == "English") {
       if(Student_id == 0 || getMarks(Student_id) > 50 || subjectCount > 1 || projectCount > 0)
           someFunction(); //if someFunction is identical, this can be done
   }
   //Something else which must be done
   ```

**Edit (after the question is edited):**

For the additional condition, you can simply put it right after the `Student_id == 0` because C# will always evaluate the left most `if` condition first (for its [|| short circuit evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)).

To illustrate: for your case, this is ok:

```
if(Student_id == 0 || getMarks(Student_id) > 50){ 
    //if Student_id == 0 is true, then getMarks(Student_id) wouldn't get evaluated
}
```

But this is *not* ok:

```
if(getMarks(Student_id) > 50 || Student_id == 0){ 
    //if Student_id is 0, then getMarks(Student_id) would throw exception before Student_id == 0 is evaluated
}
```

Comment: My apologies!! I missed one condition in code. Please see my edit

Comment: Yes. Inverting `if` to reduce nesting is a good way. +1.

Comment: @user2946329 ah, yes. I like that trick too. :)

Comment: here, if Student_id is 0, getMarks(Student_id) throws error

Comment: @MicrosoftDN if `Student_id == 0`, then getMarks(Student_id) won't get evaluated... This is just `C#` specific behavior, I think it would be different for other languages

Comment: @Ian It's actually supported in [most common languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: I don't have a problem with that if only english were the only language to check.  If there were other languages, the inverted if is a sloppy solution.

Comment: @Martheen I see... I was remembering about my older days when I have to code in C for C8051 microcontroller, it wasn't supported at least at that time.. ;)

Comment: Many thanks!!! wondering why I cant realize that 1st statement evaluates first ;)

Comment: @Neil ah, yes. That is also true. I better update it for better clarification. ;)

Comment: @MicrosoftDN glad that my little tricks can be of any help for you. ;)

Comment: Great explanation!!! Hats off..

Answer (score 4):

In terms of readability, it sometimes helps to give your conditions readable names:

```
var languageIsEnglish = language == "English";
var studentIdIsNotSet = Student_id == 0;
var hasMoreThanOneSubject = subjectCount > 1;
var hasProjects = projectCount > 0;

if(languageIsEnglish && (studentIdIsNotSet || (hasMoreThanOneSubject  || hasProjects )))
{
  someFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work;

```
if(language == "English" && (Student_id == 0 || getMarks(Student_id) > 50 || subjectCount > 1 || projectCount > 0))
{
   someFunction();
}
```

Comment: Here, if Student_id is 0, getMarks throws error

Comment: Won't execute `getMarks(Student_id)` because if `Student_id` is `0` then other conditions will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(language == "English")
{
    if(Student_id == 0 || getMarks(Student_id) > 50 || subjectCount > 1 || projectCount > 0)
    {
        someFunction();
    }
}
```

Your else block doesn't offer any alternative and in fact calls the same function. In that case there is no need for another if block.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no else for the 1st if I think you can write it in one line like this

```
if(language == "English" && (Student_id == 0 || (getMarks(Student_id) > 50 || subjectCount > 1 || projectCount > 0)))
    someFunction();
```

if there is an else you can do it like this

```
if(language == "English")
{ 
    if(Student_id == 0 || getMarks(Student_id) > 50 || subjectCount > 1 || projectCount > 0)
       someFunction();
}
else
{
}
```