# Remove nested if statements

Tags: c#

Hi I'm writing a [project](https://github.com/Matthew-Dove/ContainerExpressions), and the part I'm doing now is getting bloated real fast. How can I remove this nested if statements, but still have the same behaviour?

It would be nice the the resulting code was succinct, and extra local flags weren't required. The code below might not look so bad now, but I'm planning on writing more methods, up to **T16**, you can imagine how bad these nested if statements will get.

```
using ContainerExpressions.Containers;
using System;

namespace ContainerExpressions.Expressions.Core
{
    internal static class Compose
    {
        public static Response<T> Evaluate<T>(Func<Response<T>> func) => func();

        public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
        {
            var response = new Response<TResult>();

            var result = func1();
            if (result)
            {
                response = response.WithValue(funcResult(result));
            }

            return response;
        }

        public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
        {
            var response = new Response<TResult>();

            var result1 = func1();
            if (result1)
            {
                var result2 = func2(result1);
                if (result2)
                {
                    response = response.WithValue(funcResult(result2));
                }
            }

            return response;
        }

        public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<T3>> func3, Func<T3, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
        {
            var response = new Response<TResult>();

            var result1 = func1();
            if (result1)
            {
                var result2 = func2(result1);
                if (result2)
                {
                    var result3 = func3(result2);
                    if (result3)
                    {
                        response = response.WithValue(funcResult(result3));
                    }
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

### The code I ended up creating

After the advice I revived here I got the code bloat down, and it now looks as follows:

```
using ContainerExpressions.Containers;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ContainerExpressions.Expressions.Core
{
    internal static class Compose
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
        {
            var result = func1();
            return result ? funcResult(result) : Response.Create<TResult>();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
        {
            var result = func1();
            return result ? Evaluate(() => func2(result), funcResult) : Response.Create<TResult>();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<T3>> func3, Func<T3, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
        {
            var result = func1();
            return result ? Evaluate(() => func2(result), func3, funcResult) : Response.Create<TResult>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview](http://stackexchange.codereview.com)

Comment: your link points to an incorrect website. It's [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) :)

Comment: Fine I'll move it [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123647/remove-nested-if-statements) if this question doesn't belong on this site.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383934/method-optimization/34389030#34389030), also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919015/better-way-to-write-if-else-block/34919052#34919052)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about reusing the other methods instead like this:

```
internal static class Compose
{
    public static Response<T> Evaluate<T>(Func<Response<T>> func) => func();

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
    {
        var response = new Response<TResult>();

        var result = func1();
        if (result)
        {
            response = response.WithValue(funcResult(result));
        }

        return response;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
    {
        return func1() ? Evaluate(func2, funcResult) : new Response<TResult>();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<T3>> func3, Func<T3, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
    {
        return func1() ? Evaluate(func2, func3, funcResult) : new Response<TResult>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Simon, I thought about that, it meets all my syntax dreams, but I'm concerned about the extra function calls for this approach. For exmaple if you where to compose 16 functions, that'd make 16 extra function calls then necessary (since each *Evaluate* would call the one smaller then it).

Comment: If thats a concern you could just inline the methods, that would remove the performance aspect.

Comment: That could be done using the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` attribute, however the JIT compiler might decide to inline your methods anyway if it seems fit.

Comment: Thanks I haven't used that before, but it sounds right. I'll give that a crack.

Comment: Does that attribute go on top of every method in that compose class then?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

If your code will always behave as the parts shown, you can refactor it to *early-out* returns. I show your `Evaluate<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(...)` as an example:

```
public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<T3>> func3, Func<T3, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
{
    var response = new Response<TResult>();

    if (!func1()) return response;
    if (!func2(true)) return response;
    if (!func3(true)) return response;
    return response.WithValue(funcResult(true));
}
```

So you get rid of the nesting `if` statements. And you don't need the local flag variables since you *know* that the value is `true`.

---

In combination with Simon Karlsson's answer your code could look like this:

```
public static Response<T> Evaluate<T>(Func<Response<T>> func) => func();

public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
{
    var response = new Response<TResult>();
    return func1() ? response.WithValue(funcResult(result)) : response;
}

public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
{
    var response = new Response<TResult>();
    return func1() ? Evaluate(func2, funcResult) ? : response;
}

public static Response<TResult> Evaluate<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Func<Response<T1>> func1, Func<T1, Response<T2>> func2, Func<T2, Response<T3>> func3, Func<T3, Response<TResult>> funcResult)
{
    var response = new Response<TResult>();
    return func1() ? Evaluate(func2, func3, funcResult) : response;
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate  where your coming from, the code you've shown here isn't the same as my example. The results from the func's aren't booleans. They are a type that can be implicitly cast to any *T*, and also to boo.

Comment: Coud be even more cleanly declared like `return func1() ? Evaluate(func2, funcResult) : new Response<TResult>();` on all except first!

Comment: Oh, didn't recognize that important part ;) But then the code you showed does not compile at all? Because `if (result)` only compiles if `result` is `bool`.

Comment: @RenéVogt It does compile [see here](https://github.com/Matthew-Dove/ContainerExpressions/blob/master/ContainerExpressions/ContainerExpressions/Containers/Response.cs#L40), I like the combination of your's and Simon's answers, I'm going to use both approaches combined into one.

Comment: @user1515024 ah ok, seems I have been working too long for today, didn't think about cast operators.